# Creating a history Table using existing table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class named Employee with mapping to employee.hbm.xml . I have new requirement that i should have a history table i.e Employee_history that should keep the records of the Employee table with new extra fields like lastUpdated and dateCreated . When i create or update new records into the Employee then it should be updated into the Employee_History table also .
So what should be the better approach to do it ?
I'm very new to hibernate or could say started today itself .Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple approach would be to INSERT the modified record (off course with the old values) into the history table. May require some changes in the code. So wherever you are saving the edited record in the code, just add a couple of lines to move the existing record into the history table, along with additional fields that you require like lastupdated, etc.

Comment: One think more i would like to know . In earlier projects i have used grails framework where i have used Date lastUpdated and Date dateCreated . It worked in grails. Do we have such things in hibernate only so that i can use it for lastUpdated or dateCreated?
Actually i could not find good example on net .

Answer (score 6):

[Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers) does that for you:

> The Envers project aims to enable easy auditing/versioning of persistent classes. All that you have to do is annotate your persistent class or some of its properties, that you want to audit, with @Audited. For each audited entity, a table will be created, which will hold the history of changes made to the entity. You can then retrieve and query historical data without much effort.

Comment: it only works for Hibernate 3.5 but i'm using lower version of hibernate. So anymore solutions ? thanx in advance :)

Comment: Hibernate 3.5 is already very old. Why don't you update to a more recent version? BTW, what makes you think Envers only works for 3.5?

Comment: Actuallu i'm working on a client project and they have used hibernate 3.0 . So i'm 'Envers' would be very gud idea to use it . But can we use Envers to this version  ?